# How to check if an ellipse passes through an elliptical ring?

Tags: geometry

This is a question for a problem that I need to solve for a personal project.

Say I have an elliptical ring with a certain angle represented by the equation:
$r_1^2 + p^2>\frac{(x\cdot cos(\alpha _1)+y\cdot sin(\alpha _1))^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{(x\cdot sin(\alpha _1)-y\cdot cos(\alpha _1))^2}{b_1^2}> r_1^2-p^2$

Where $r_1$ is the radius of the ring, and p is the thickness.

How would I check whether or not an ellipse with a certain angle represented by another equation: $\frac{(x\cdot cos(\alpha _2)+y\cdot sin(\alpha _2))^2}{a_2^2}+\frac{(x\cdot sin(\alpha _2)-y\cdot cos(\alpha _2))^2}{b_2^2}=r_2^2$   passes through the ring?

Where $r_2$ is the radius of the ellipse.

For context, I'm working on a personal project in unity and I need to check whether or not the orbit of an object around a star passes through the orbit of the hillsphere of another object (hence a ring instead of an ellipse for the first equation) in such a way that can be checked with an algorithm.
I guess I could check whether or not the ellipse intersects with any of the two ellipses of the ring, but that wouldn't account for the unlikely case where the ellipse would be contained within the two rings?

I'm not at university level, as I said this is just a personal project I'm working on.

Thank you for reading and helping!

[An example of the problem: the ring is the area between the blue and red dotted lines, the green curve is the ellipse that, in this case, passes through the ring.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXrpS.png)

Comment: Your first equation doesn't make much sense.  Please check it.  I think you have to modify its bounds.

Comment: I forgot to say that r is the radius of the ring's ellipse, and p is the thickness of the ring. I'll edit the post.
If I enter these into desmos then I get a ring and an ellipse.

Comment: Ahhh now I see what you mean, yes I think I got the inequalities mixed up.